# find a substring inside a bash variable

Tags: bash

we were trying to find the username of a mercurial url:

```
default = ssh://someone@acme.com//srv/hg/repo
```

Suppose that there's always a username, I came up with:

```
tmp=${a#*//}
user=${tmp%%@*}
```

Is there a way to do this in one line?

Comment: Does using a semi-colon between the two operations (instead of a newline) count?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your string is in a variable like this:

```
url='default = ssh://someone@acme.com//srv/hg/repo'
```

You can do:

```
[[ $url =~ //([^@]*)@ ]]
```

Then your username is here:

```
echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

This works in Bash versions 3.2 and higher.

Answer (score 3):

You pretty much need more that one statement or to call out to external tools. I think sed is best for this.

```
sed -r -e 's|.*://(.*)@.*|\1|' <<< "$default"
```

Comment: I don't remember seeing that construct before - the `<<<` - so I just learned something new. Usually I `echo` the variable into `sed`; I would imagine this construct is more efficient?

Comment: I imagine it is, since an echo and a pipe means a whole 'nother subshell whereas a here string is handled in process.

Answer (score 0):

Not within bash itself. You'd have to delegate to an external tool such as sed.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with mercurial, but using your url, you can do

```
echo 'ssh://someone@acme.com/srv/hg/repo' |grep -E --only-matching '\w+@' |cut --delimiter=\@ -f 1
```

Probably not the most efficient way with the two pipes, but works.